# How to deserialise a JSON object where the object structure is not known

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Part of my code serializes file paths of a machine into JSON in the below format. I am struggling to take this JSON and put the file paths back together again.  I am using Newtonsoft JSON lib; I find it's excellent for building JSON. As you can see, my JSON has nested objects.

The JSON I have:

```
{
  ".": {
    "proc": {
      "15": {
        "task": {
          "15": {
            "exe": {},
            "mounts": {
              "list_of_files": [
                "mounts.xml"
              ]
            },
            "mountinfo": {
              "list_of_files": [
                "mountinfo.xml"
              ]
            },
            "clear_refs": {
              "list_of_files": [
                "clear_ref.xml"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "14": {
        "loginuid": {
          "list_of_files": [
            "loginuid.xml"
          ]
        },
        "sessionid": {
          "list_of_files": [
            "sessionid.xml"
          ]
        },
        "coredump_filter": {
          "list_of_files": [
            "coredump_filter.xml"
          ]
        },
        "io": {
          "list_of_files": [
            "io.xml"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The array I want to generate from this.

```
string[] dirArray = {
"./proc/15/task/15/exe",
"./proc/15/task/15/mounts/mounts.xml",
"./proc/15/task/15/mountinfo/mountinfo.xml",
"./proc/15/task/15/clear_refs/clear_ref.xml",
"./proc/14/loginuid/loginuid.xml",
"./proc/14/sessionid/sessionid.xml",
"./proc/14/coredump_filter/coredump_filter.xml",
"./proc/14/io/io.xml"
}
```

My efforts so far-- I deserialised the JSON into a dynamic variable but I'm not sure how to handle two issues:

1. My JSON format is unknown, I don't know how deep the objects go, how can I handle this?
2. How do I work with dynamic variables when they are defined at run-time?

**EDIT**

Sorry, my original JSON format was wrong, so it doesn't work with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26717924/10263) provided by user12864.  I'm getting an error: `Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.`

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XUrFG4) showing where I'm at so far.

Comment: Might I suggest you abandon all the hierarchy and instead just store each path as a complete path? The `Path` API in .NET should be sufficient for determining the hierarchy from code. The whole thing would be much easier to handle, and the resulting JSON would be more readable.

Comment: But if all i have is the json, i need to get the path from that. Maybe i misunderstand your comment? The reason for the json in first place is to allow a UI consumer to display in a navigable way, the paths. The code i am writing now is to understand which paths they have chosen to keep, the UI will edit the json and send back, i need to deconstruct to paths in order to do some tasks.

Comment: I'm saying you should change your format. Just have it be a JSON array of files, don't store it in such a hierarchical way.

Comment: Unfortunately, its in a hierarchical way to help  a consuming component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@user12864](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26717924/10263) has the right idea in his answer, but the code needs to be adjusted to account for the fact that each directory can have an array of files rather a single "file" object (you really should have mentioned that in your question originally).  Here is an updated method to handle that:

```
private static void AddToFileList(JObject jo, List<string> list, string prefix)
{
    foreach (var kvp in jo)
    {
        if (kvp.Key == "list_of_files")
        {
            foreach (string name in (JArray)kvp.Value)
            {
                list.Add(prefix + name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            JObject dir = (JObject)kvp.Value;
            if (dir.Count == 0)
            {
                list.Add(prefix + kvp.Key);
            }
            else
            {
                AddToFileList(dir, list, prefix + kvp.Key + "/");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full demo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
          ""."": {
            ""proc"": {
              ""15"": {
                ""task"": {
                  ""15"": {
                    ""exe"": {},
                    ""mounts"": {
                      ""list_of_files"": [
                        ""mounts.xml""
                      ]
                    },
                    ""mountinfo"": {
                      ""list_of_files"": [
                        ""mountinfo.xml""
                      ]
                    },
                    ""clear_refs"": {
                      ""list_of_files"": [
                        ""clear_ref.xml""
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              ""14"": {
                ""loginuid"": {
                  ""list_of_files"": [
                    ""loginuid.xml""
                  ]
                },
                ""sessionid"": {
                  ""list_of_files"": [
                    ""sessionid.xml""
                  ]
                },
                ""coredump_filter"": {
                  ""list_of_files"": [
                    ""coredump_filter.xml""
                  ]
                },
                ""io"": {
                  ""list_of_files"": [
                    ""io.xml""
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }";

        JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
        foreach (string path in CreateFileList(jo))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(path);
        }
    }

    private static List<string> CreateFileList(JObject jo)
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();
        AddToFileList(jo, ret, "");
        return ret;
    }

    private static void AddToFileList(JObject jo, List<string> list, string prefix)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in jo)
        {
            if (kvp.Key == "list_of_files")
            {
                foreach (string name in (JArray)kvp.Value)
                {
                    list.Add(prefix + name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                JObject dir = (JObject)kvp.Value;
                if (dir.Count == 0)
                {
                    list.Add(prefix + kvp.Key);
                }
                else
                {
                    AddToFileList(dir, list, prefix + kvp.Key + "/");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
./proc/15/task/15/exe
./proc/15/task/15/mounts/mounts.xml
./proc/15/task/15/mountinfo/mountinfo.xml
./proc/15/task/15/clear_refs/clear_ref.xml
./proc/14/loginuid/loginuid.xml
./proc/14/sessionid/sessionid.xml
./proc/14/coredump_filter/coredump_filter.xml
./proc/14/io/io.xml
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/r8CkI2

Comment: Thats it Brian. That is abs fantastic, lesson learnt on the sample json, that was my fault. You understood issue straight away (despite me) and solved it so eloquently. thx again sir. Il wait for a few hours so i can add a bounty and then mark as solved.

Answer (score 2):

This should give exactly what you're looking for; just create a `JObject` with `JObject.Parse` and pass it to `CreateFileList`.  It won't handle malformed JSON in any nice way.

```
    static List<string> CreateFileList(JObject j)
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();
        AddToFileList(j, ret, "");
        return ret;
    }


    static void AddToFileList(JObject j, List<string> dest, string prefix)
    {
        if (prefix.Length != 0)
            prefix = prefix + '/';

        foreach (var kvp in j)
        {
            var jnext = (JObject)kvp.Value;
            if (kvp.Key == "file")
                dest.Add(prefix + (string)jnext["name"]);
            else
                AddToFileList(jnext, dest, prefix + kvp.Key);
        }
    }
```

Fiddle at https://dotnetfiddle.net/dQQ4tI

Comment: Fantatsic, i am getting a error however: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'

Comment: That and other similar sorts of errors will occur on JSON that doesn't exactly match the layout expected.  I tested this exact code on the exact JSON text you posted and had no errors.

Comment: Actually, the issue is that the file path JSON is 1 level down from the root node, i need to select the files parent object and then use above code, il update question eg.

Comment: hmmm nope, still cant see issue, would it be possible to fork this fiddle and show me with the example json in question?

dotnetfiddle.net/YOMurg

Comment: Massive apologies, I have hit a problem that i have recreated and i think its' caused by fact that my JSON object actually looks like this once i parse down to the files node, see fiddle below. 

https://dotnetfiddle.net/XUrFG4

Comment: @Fearghal I've updated your question with the corrected JSON format  per your comments and added an answer with an updated method to handle that.  In the future, please be careful to put accurate details in your question, otherwise you end up wasting people's time.

Comment: I will do, i just noticed it wasnt you that added the updated answer below which is same approach but updated for my updated json. Once again, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

---

Here is a revised answer, after you clarified your requirement of:

> The JavaScript Object Notation is built on the server, edited by user through a hierarchical tree interface component. That can be crawled incredibly easy.

So in essence your utilizing a component, in which your hoping to build simple JavaScript Object Notation derived from the component. Your *User Interface* will be unknown, so I'll make some presumptions.

*Build our Object:*

```
public class XmlPath
{
     public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

The `XmlPath` will represent our object.  Which will be basic auto property.

*Add Content to our Object:*

```
private List<XmlPath> AddXmlPath(List<string> location)
{
     List<XmlPath> content = new List<XmlPath>();
     foreach(string item in location)
          content.Add(new XmlPath() { Location = item });

     return content;           
}
```

This will be incredibly simple method, it will take a large `List<string>` of your user data and add them to your `XmlPath` object.

*Remove content from our Object:*

```
private List<XmlPath> RemoveXmlPath(List<XmlPath> root, string location)
{
     root.Remove(new XmlPath() { Location = location });
     return root;
}
```

Those two methods truly don't need to be, I'm just demonstrating and showing how you could.  Plus it will outline the intentions a bit easier for you to implement.  Please note this is incredibly crude approach.

*Serialize / Deserialize Our Object to JavaScript Objection Notation:*

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var xmlPath = AddXmlPath(List<string> location);
var result = serializer.Serialize(xmlPath);
var deserialize = serializer.Deserialize(List<XmlPath>>(result);
```

Our content is exposed now through a basic loop:

```
foreach(XmlPath item in deserialize)
{
     // Exposed Model via 'item.Location'
}
```

You'll simply need to correlate this core functionality to your implementation.  The approach is crude, quite rudimentary, definitely will need to be improved on for production.  However this should get you started with:

- Serialize data on the server.
- Deserialize server data.
- Manipulating the object.

Hope this is better for you.

Comment: No its a the json (built on the server) edited by user in a hierarchical tree interface component. Because the user may remove any node of the json (i use json to allow easy navigation) i need to be able to crawl through every part of it. the example covers what it could look like.

Comment: I've revised my answer for you.